# Catching system default editor closing event in java

Tags: java, file, system, desktop

I have a Windows program with the following flow:

```
generated config file -> user edits config file -> use config file
```

Ideally I want to launch the system default editor for the given file type/extension (.cfg, .ini, .txt), which can be done with [`java.awt.Desktop.edit()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html).

But since the program continues execution once the editor has started, I have no idea how to check that the user actually closed the editor again `:\`

I have seen this be done in numeous applications, albeit most on Linux and probably non-java.

Also, since users are "stupid", configuring a default editor from within my application is way too complicated. It might be acceptable to use a standard program, e.g. notepad which is ensured to *almost* always be installed on Windows computers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just figured out the notepad solution -- doh! it was quite obvious :)

Use [`Runtime.exec()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29) and [`Process.waitFor()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29):

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime.exec("notepad " + filename);
p.waitFor();
```